# How to delete a file inside a zip archive without decompressing?

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, archiving

I have a large zip file and I can't decompress it because I don't have enough space so I am going through all the files inside and first copying them to an outer folder and then deleting them.  I can copy the files out of the archive one by one just fine, but when I try to delete the file I get this error:

[image: error]

I am fairly certain that this is because my computer is trying to decompress the zip file before deleting the file.  Is there a way to directly delete a file in a zip archive, without decompressing it?  I am open to using cmd for this.

Comment: Try another utility, like 7-zip.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 7-zip looks like it would work but it says that the folders inside the zip files are zero bytes even though they are >10 GB.